# No wifi after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking

Wifi was working fine, I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 and now no Wifi is available. There is no Wifi widget in the task bar.

This is with kernel 5.15.0-27-generic and also 5.13.0. `apt list` shows `linux-modules-5.11.0` is available however this does not show up in the grub menu and the first two do.

With kernel 5.15 I can do USB tethering for network access. With 5.13, this did not work.

Settings > Network shows "PCI Ethernet" (Cable unplugged), "USB Ethernet" (Connected), and "VPN" (Not set up) sections.

What's wrong and how can I fix it?

`ifconfig | grep :`

```
br-02a96324548b: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 02:42:6c:51:a7:d7  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
br-5d1de55dd0ca: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 02:42:5c:df:35:b6  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 02:42:08:47:51:31  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
enp4s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether f0:2f:74:db:b6:da  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::e3ae:37aa:219f:7865  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether a2:a7:fa:bb:4a:09  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

iwconfig:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp4s0    no wireless extensions.

br-02a96324548b  no wireless extensions.

br-5d1de55dd0ca  no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.

usb0      no wireless extensions.
```

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:05.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 61)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse/Vermeer Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse/Vermeer Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse/Vermeer Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse/Vermeer Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse/Vermeer Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse/Vermeer Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse/Vermeer Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse/Vermeer Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 7
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Phison Electronics Corporation E16 PCIe4 NVMe Controller (rev 01)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Switch Upstream
03:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge
03:08.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge
03:09.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge
03:0a.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse PCIe GPP Bridge
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 26)
05:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Reserved SPP
05:00.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller
05:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller
06:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51)
07:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51)
08:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 [GeForce RTX 3080] (rev a1)
08:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
09:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Function
0a:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Reserved SPP
0a:00.1 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Cryptographic Coprocessor PSPCPP
0a:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller
0a:00.4 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller
```

lsusb:

```
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 005: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 005 Device 004: ID 046d:0a4c Logitech, Inc. Logi Z407
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 0bda:c811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c077 Logitech, Inc. M105 Optical Mouse
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0b05:18f3 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. AURA LED Controller
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1b1c:0c0b Corsair Lighting Node Pro
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1b1c:0c22 Corsair iCUE H150i RGB PRO XT Liquid CPU Cooler
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04e8:6863 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy series, misc. (tethering mode)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 045e:07f8 Microsoft Corp. Wired Keyboard 600 (model 1576)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Same for me here. Had a similar experience when upgrading from 18 to 19 when it did not boot at all. Question now is what is worse. But this limits me to places with a wired connection. No real place to complain about such a serious issue, one of the things Open Source really has to come up with an answer to, because this kind of failure is killing OSS while propriety vendors are the laughing party here.
No f-ing way to just reinstall the proper drivers here to make up. 
Never upgrade to .4 again only to .10 so another 5 months till this thing "automagically" heals itself.

Comment: if not who can tell.. back to W again?? I that really the grand scheme ? Are there payed Linux/Ubuntu devs, well payed by the dominant market parties screwing thing up for specific hardware so many are hurt but core devs with certain other hardware do never feel that pain?